# Using inline variable for naming outputs in ModelBuilder

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, buffer, workflow, variables

I am using ModelBuilder in ArcMap 10.8.2.

The model I built allows a user to enter in multiple Logging System Names with their associated buffer distances. I want the outputs created by the model to have the user defined logging system name with "_buffer" at the end. My problem is that the model will name the first user defined input correctly, and then names the rest of the outputs something generic. How do I ensure that the inline variable will be used to name each output?
I included a screenshot of my model below. I am wondering if the problem lies in the Calculate Value step because it looks like one Output Value is produced instead of multiple, even though the input is multivalue.

[image: LoggingModel]
[image: CalculateValue]
[image: UserEndTool]

Comment: I think you have hit the nail on the head, calculate value is executing only once. I've never found multiple values intuitive in modelbuilder, consider exploring the use of an iterator to create the looping nature of your workflow? Or as a long shot try sticking the calculate value tool into a sub-model? But that's me just guessing...